# Java, how to use computeIfAbsent computeIfPresent to fulfil this purpose?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashmap, factory

I'm trying to make a Factory with the following function:

- it should always return a Filter object.
- Either from the hashmap =  if the String letters (key) already exists in the hashmap, it should just take its value (object) from the hashmap and return it.
- or a new one if the hashmap doesn't have that key then create a new object and return it.

The program shall work in the following order according to the user input:

```
 //user first input. 
 String letters="aaa"; // creat new object. 
 //user second input. 
 String letters="fff"; // creat new object. 

 String letters="aaa"; //dont make a new object and return the object and return the object of the first input.
```

To do this I've thought of the following:

- first what I had in my mind was to use hashmaps.
- by assigning `String letters` as key and the object `Filter` as value.
- next i wanted to compare if the key hasn't been entered before then create a new object if the key already exists then return its object.

Here is what I wrote for the moment:

(FactoryClass)

```
 //if i let this i will getjava.lang.NullPointerException
 //private static Filter filter = null;
 public static Filter getFilter(String letters){

        Filter filter=new Filter(letters);

        HashMap <String, Object> hmap = new HashMap< String , Object> ();

        hmap.put(letters,filter);

        //for the first run is true because the map has yet only one pair of <k,v>
        if (hmap.containsKey(letters))
        {
            System.out.println("return the obj where there is a key match");//i will remove this later cz the user doesnt care about it. 
            //so i will return the filter object that has been created here "hmap.put(letters,filter);" by returning the value that matches the key.
            return (Filter) hmap.get(letters);  

        } else {//if the user didn't enter the same key then a new object shall be created!.

            System.out.println("new object has been generated");//i will remove this late cz the user doent care about it.
            //if the entered letters(key) isnt found in the map then put it in the map and creat new object. 
            hmap.put(letters, filter);

            return filter;
        }
    }
```

Constructor in the other class is protected and the factory will get the string letters per user input from the main method.
any help would be appreciated, but please demonstrate your suggestions in java code.

well, this apparently doesnt solve the problem but how to solve the probelm?

so i searched online and i found the computeIfAbsent but i dont know exactly how to use it. 
on the java orcale doc this is what written and 
`hmap.computeIfAbsent(letters, k -> new Filter (k) );`

now i dont get what does this 'k' mean here nor what is meant with this "->"
i tried to use it as above but i got some errors:

- k cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "-", "--" expected
- l cannot be resolved to a variable

  1. First question how shall the code look like when using the computeIfAbsent?
  2. Is there anyway where i can get what i want without using those computeIfAbsent and coputeIfPresent?

i already have the following in the class filter

```
public class Filter {
private final String letters;

    protected Filter(String letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
while(true){
    //Scanner to allow user to give input!.
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("please enter the filter stirng!");

    String filter= in.next();
 }
}


 public static Filter getFilter(String letters) {
          Filter obj = hmap.get(letters);
          if (obj == null) {
             obj = new Filter(letters);
             hmap.put(letters, obj);
          }
          return obj;
       }
```

Comment: Why do you need an array to store keys? You already have the keys.

Comment: yeah, I have the String letters (keys) but to check if the key exists or not I told to myself that I would store the keys in an array then compare them. but after all its unachievable because I don't know how many key im going to have thus I'm not able to make an array. but I would like to know how the code would look like using computeIfAbsent. (i will edit the question and remove the array thing. )

Comment: @Dave Newton would you pls help to solve the problem if you can?

Comment: @javanoob I provided you an answer.  If the key already exists, it returns the existing object.  If it doesn't exist, it creates an object, stores it in the map, and returns that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't explain your errors.  I see no apparent syntax problems.  I edited the answer to include a vanilla, pre-java8 method.

Comment: thanks for trying to help

Comment: Could it be that Eclipse doesn't recognize Java 1.8 and is pointing to an older version? Check your compiler settings under `window->preferences->java->compiler`.

Comment: i work on raspbian and the result of the javac -version
is -- ->> javac 1.8.0_181

Comment: but thanks for your help.i will try to reinstall the JDK again I guess.

Comment: It's not the Java version I am enquiring about.  It is the ability of Eclipse to understand specific version capabilities.  That is independent of the version of Java you have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Filter f = FilterFactory.getFilter("aaa"); // call from user1
          Filter g = FilterFactory.getFilter("bbb"); // call from user2
          Filter h = FilterFactory.getFilter("aaa"); // call from user3
          System.out.println(f == h); // same filter
    }

    class FilterFactory {
       private static Map<String, Filter> map = new HashMap<>();

       private FilterFactory() {
       }

       public static Filter getFilter(String letters) {
          return map.computeIfAbsent(letters, Filter::new);
       }

 // Pre-java 8 version
       public static Filter getFilter2(String letters) {
          Filter f = map.get(letters);
          if (f == null) {
             f = new Filter(letters);
             map.put(letters, f);
          }
          return f;
       }

    class Filter {
       String f;

       public Filter(String f) {
          this.f = f;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return f;
       }
    }
```

In all instances, the Key to the hashMap is the argument to the filter constructor.

- For method references it is implied.
- For lambdas it is the local variable (k in the above examples).

Note: Java 8+ required for this to work.

Comment: hello thanks for helping the problem with your solution is that you're supposed to know the keys in order to make this work. (which i dont the user has to make the letters from main method.). and that was my using the  FilterFactory method.

Comment: What does the user have that allows them to select the proper filter?

Comment: let's assume we have the following scenario: the user gives the ``String letters="aaa";`` now the factory will look up the newly entered key and make a new object ``Filter`` then put them in the hashmap and afterwards it will return the object. 
till now we don't have a problem but if the user now makes a new input with the same letters like ``String letters="aaa";`` the program shall not create a new object because this key matches the other key thus the factory shall return the same object of the previously entered key. now the problem how shall I compare the keys without storing them?!.

Comment: That is what I did.  The original code was to demonstrate the `computeIfAbsent` feature.  Look at the edited code.

Comment: You need to store the keys in the map.  Otherwise, there is no way to retrieve the proper filter unless you do a linear search of the filters and grab them that way.  That is very inefficient.

Comment: sir i tried to compile ``return hmap.computeIfAbsent ( letters , Filter :: new);`` but as soon as i paste the line in eclipse i got some red lines from the compiler. 
pls look the post i added your approach and commented what problems i got.

Comment: yub the Pre-java 8 version version worked just fine.